# How to return multiple in java, jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two objects, Student and Book. Student has @OneToMany relationship with Book, and Book has only id, name, and publishYear. What i want is to return from Query is this -> Select s.name, b.name, b.publishYear from Student s inner join Book b on s.id = b.studentId. How to return s.name, b.name and b.publishYear?

Answer (score 0):

```
entityManager.createQuery("select s.name, b.name, b.publishYear from Student s join s.books b");
```

This will return a `List<Object[]>`

If you want to return a list of DTOs you can use the constructor expression:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select new model.BookDTO(s.name, b.name, b.publishYear) from Student s join s.books b");
```

This will return a `List<BookDTO>`

The BookDTO must look like this:

```
package model;

public class BookDTO() {

    private final String studentName;
    private final String bookName;
    private final String publishYear;

    public BookDTO(String studentName, String bookName, String publishYear) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.publishYear = publishYear;
    }

    // getters
}
```

Read more about projection in the Hibernate documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause